# Encoding and Decoding Base64 Python / Salesforce

Tags: apex, python, simple-salesforce

I’m working on a small python script to export ContentVersion records from one Salesforce org and migrate them into another. I’m using simple-salesforce. I am able to export the ContentVersion and the relayed VersionData. I’m running into issues with figuring out what to do with the VersionData response and what the appropriate decide / encode process is to then resend the content version to the new org. The files are always corrupted and don’t open.

Here's sample code, note I'm doing this in a colab notebook:

```python
#Query Content Files
#GET SOURCE NOTES
content_doc_source_data = source_sf.query_all("SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, ContentLocation, ContentUrl, Description, FileExtension, FileType, IsLatest, OwnerId, PathOnClient, SharingOption, SharingPrivacy, Title, VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE FileType !='SNOTE'")
content_doc_source_data_df = pd.DataFrame(content_doc_source_data['records']).drop(columns='attributes')

content_doc_source_data_df
```

This returns a table, and you can see there's a path for the ContentDoc itself in VersionData.
[image]

So then I'm iterating through that table and querying the VersionData:

```python
import json

headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % access_token
    }

for index, row in content_doc_source_data_df.iterrows():
  r = requests.request('get', instance_url+'/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/'+row['Id']+'/VersionData', headers=headers)
  content_doc_source_data_df.at[index, 'File Body'] = r.text
  break

display(content_doc_source_data_df)
```

I then add the file body to the table just so I can interact with it, see picture below:
[image]

I think my question more specifically is, what should I be returning from the response (e.g., text, content, etc.) and then what are the next steps to decode/encode so that I can then insert that file into another Salesforce org.

You can see "File Body" column above. I was looking for guidance on converting it to base64 string.

I'm specifically looking for guidance on the best way to "decode" the file body and then turn around and decode it so I can send it to another Salesforce org.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting those question-mark replacement characters is the content that's coming back to you isn't text - but you're asking Python / `requests` to interpret the content as if it were.

You need to work with this content [as a binary response](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content), using the `r.content` property on the response object. That will give you a `bytes` object, rather than a `str`.

Then, to insert arbitrary content that you have in a `bytes` as a new `ContentVersion`, you'd call the [Insert ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm#inserting_a_contentversion) endpoint by using `requests`'s [multipart-encoded request support](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file), something like this (untested code, written here!):

```python
def upload_content_version(
    file_name: str,
    content: bytes,
    instance_url: str,
    access_token: str
) -> Response:
    return requests.post( 
        f"{instance_url}/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/ContentVersion",
        data={"PathOnClient": file_name},
        headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"},
        files={
            "file": (filename, content, "application/octet-stream")
        }
    );
```

Comment: Interesting, I'm using the simple-salesforce python library. I'll need to see what options i have for adjusting some of these items. But it seems like what you're saying is r.content will by a bytes object, no need to encode/decode that item. That's ultimately what would get cast to "VersionData". Then I should be able to adjust my header to be application/octet stream.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to solve a very similar migration usecase, and adapting the requests multipart support to match *exactly* what Salesforce is expecting (from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm) took me some time.

In case it saves anyone else from spending a lot of time doing the same thing, here is the Python code I ended up with. Key points to note are (1) while the standard API requires that you pass **base64 encoded** ContentVersion data, the multipart API requires **binary data**. And (2) a little off-topic, but if your ContentVersion is ultimately going to be attached or embedded in a Chatter post that you are also migrating, you need to pass Origin and NetworkId to the request so it can inherit the sharing permissions of the community (otherwise these should be omitted).

```
def upload_content_version(file_name, file_path, instance_url, access_token, network_id):

    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % access_token}

    data = {
        'Title': file_name,
        'PathOnClient': file_name,
        'NetworkId': network_id,    # if using in a Chatter post
        'Origin': 'H'               # if using in a Chatter post
    }

    # Salesforce expects binary data in the multipart request, NOT base64 encoded
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        file_content = file.read()

    files = {
        'entity_content': (None, json.dumps(data), 'application/json'),
        'VersionData': (file_name, file_content, 'application/octet-stream')
    }

    url = instance_url + '/services/data/v54.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/'
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
```