# Standard content version api is storing the binary content as is in the object without converting it as actual file

Tags: rest-api, api, contentversion, curl

I am trying to upload a file >50MB to Salesforce Content version object with reference to the Standard ContentVersion API

API Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm

I am using curl to send the request. Below is the curl command

`curl https://MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v59.0/sobjects/ContentVersion -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=\"boundary_string\"" --data-binary @NewContentVersion.json`

And this is the NewContentVersion.json which getting passed in the CURL request

```
--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content";
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "Title":"<file-name>",
    "PathOnClient":"<file-name>",
    "ContentLocation":"S",
    "FirstPublishLocationId":"<record-id>"
}

--boundary_string
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="<file-name>"

<Base64 encoded data goes here>

--boundary_string--
```

The API call is successfull and the file has also created and published in the specified location ID `'"FirstPublishLocationId":"<record-id>"'`

But the file seems to contain the Base64 encoded data only. I expect that the file should be available in its actual format. When I download the file from salesforce, I see that the Base64 encoded data is there in the downloaded content and not the actual file.

[image: Image from published location]

With reference to the above Image, The last file in the list(5.63MB) is in correct format of the file which was also uploaded from same API, but the API header content-type is not multipart/form when I uploaded from API since it is a small file. I uploaded by adding the base64 encoded value in the 'VersionData' field in the Request Body. And it converted to actual file in the salesforce.

The remaining files (top to last but one) in the list were large files and I uploaded from the same API with Content-Type as multipart/form. But these files are not base64 decoded when they are saved in the ContentVersion.

Am I missing something in the Request or do I need to send Content-Type=Multipart/form differently due to which the base64 decode is not working in the API call ?

Any help or advise on this is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: See this Q&A https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/385336/encoding-and-decoding-base64-python-salesforce , it has your answer